# HTML Table row in React component is not responding to my css styles in order to limit the height of the content

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass, html-table

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-fog-nwu30?file=/src/styles.css:0-525)I have a component in my application where I'm to work with Html table. But the problem I'm having now is That I needed to limit the height and width of the row to a particular fixed size. I tried applying height and overflow on the rows but it wasn't working. Here

Attached is the codesandbox link

HTML TABLE IN REACT COMPONENT ROW (TR) NOT RESPONDING TO CSS STYLING TO LIMIT THE HEIGHT OF THE CONTENT

is what I have done below.

App.css

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <table id="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>  bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    </td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
</table>




    </div>
  );
}
```

Style.css

```
/* .App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
} */

#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem?  Which specific style rule isn't applying to which specific element as expected?

Comment: I just added a codesandox link @David I needed the first row to ahve a particular width and height fixed all all rows in this situation ...maybe hide all other contents with overflow

Comment: That sandbox link shows no HTML table.

Comment: It's a Html table in a react component @David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a solution. Check if that works for you. I have created max-width for the table td and added thead and tbody for being semantically correct.

```css
#customers {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

#customers td,
#customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#customers tr:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#customers th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04aa6d;
  color: white;
}

tbody tr td {
  max-width: 100px;
}
tbody tr td div {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <table id="customers">
  <thead>
<tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>  <div>
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    bvgsbdhbhksbhsbuihbsn nbhbhsbdh, sbhsb shbdhb vbhbjhbsjnbjsnjs k njlnljnljnjnjnb njnjjnjnj 
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>North/South</td>
    <td>Simon Crowther</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paris spécialités</td>
    <td>Marie Bertrand</td>
    <td>France</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




    </div>
```

Comment: Yes. Please tell me